# Android doesn't send SMS message without user interaction

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions, smsmanager

I'm developing an android application that sends text messages. The shipping code is this

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.BIND_CARRIER_SERVICES" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Code:

```
     SmsManager smsManager
                    = SmsManager.getDefault();

            smsManager.sendTextMessage( sms.getNumber(), providerNumber,
                                        sms.getContent(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

But when the app works the message remains in default SMS app as not sent. I' ve to enter to default app and touch one by one and it sends.

This is my build.gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"                            
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:1.4.0' //for JVM
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:1.4.0' //for Android
compile 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-rxjava:1.4.0' //for RxJava support
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What is the provider number which you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution... it was that I thought. Trouble is that I was trying to send SMS from another Thread. It's assumed to send from Main Ui Thread. 
The code provided by Google works only in Main UI Thread. Currently I'm trying to use a service to see if works!

Answer (score 0):

To send the messages using the default provider you need to use "null" as the provider argument 
Like this

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage( sms.getNumber(), null, sms.getContent(), sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

I am using this

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

in one of my app and this works perfectly.

Note: 23+ app need to have the  element(s) in manifest, but you also have to ask for those permissions at runtime from the user on Android 6.0+ devices, using methods like

```
checkSelfPermission()
```

and

```
requestPermissions()
```

Comment: I used null and also I tried with the number provided by my carrier. (Not my phone number)

Comment: try this way passing static argument and nulls and check whether it works directly or not.    `smsManager.sendTextMessage( enter_some_static_number_here, null, "Hello", null, null);`

Comment: I am using this `smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);` in one of my app and that works perfectly.

Comment: Despite the suggested changes it's still not working.

Comment: share you build.gradle (app level) . what is the targetSdkVersion ? and on which device API you are testing the app? As 23+ app need to have the `<uses-permission>` element(s), but you also have to ask for those permissions at runtime from the user on Android 6.0+ devices, using methods like `checkSelfPermission()` and `requestPermissions()`.

Comment: It's an internal app. I assigned the permissions before start it from App settings in Android settings menu --> Apps. I edited the question with build.gradle settings

Comment: i just used this  on a button and its working perfectly  `SmsManager smsManager
                = SmsManager.getDefault();

        smsManager.sendTextMessage( "+923348962680", null,
                "Hello", null, null);` in my app and it is working.  What